# How to get the value from the below output in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap

I am getting this below output while hitting soap service and now I want to fetch the all value from the below output. How to get this?

```
[{
    "sms": "You have logged in successfully!",
    "userId": "13",
    "type": "1",
    "name": "Suhashini Kumari Singh"
}]
```

Comment: show code where you are getting this response in

Comment: hello think twice before going to downvote, if u know the answer tell me otherwise Do Nothing.

Comment: Brother I will help you show your code please

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
  NSArray *yourArr;  // your array which you have post in question

NSDictionary *obj1 = [yourArr objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *sms = [obj1 objectForKey:@"sms"];

NSString *userId = [obj1 objectForKey:@"userId"];

NSString *name = [obj1 objectForKey:@"name"];

NSString *type = [obj1 objectForKey:@"type"];
```

You can go loop through if you have multiple object in array!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create class with needed properties and map this response with framework like [EasyMapping](https://github.com/lucasmedeirosleite/EasyMapping)