# How to parse the data into Json Format in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, soap

I Converted NSData to string then I am getting the string like below, Now I want to parse this one. If parse with json serilazation I am getting json data nil.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><EmployeesLoginMethodResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><EmployeesLoginMethodResult>[{"sms":"You have logged in successfully!","userId":"29","type":"1","name":"mng 56 78"}]</EmployeesLoginMethodResult></EmployeesLoginMethodResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

If I parse using **XML** I am Getting The **String** Like below,In this How to get value of **sms**,**userId**,**name**

```
 [{
  "sms": "You have logged in successfully!",
  "userId": "13",
  "type": "1",
  "name": "Suhashini Kumari Singh"
 }]
```

Here is my code

```
   NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://workforce.wifisocial.in/WebServicesMethods/EmployeesWebService.asmx"];
NSString* webStringURL = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSString* requestBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><EmployeesLoginMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><username>\%@</username><password>\%@</password><IpAddress>\%@</IpAddress><deviceName>\%@</deviceName></EmployeesLoginMethod></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",self.userNameTextFiled.text,self.passwordTextField.text,ipAddress,deviceName];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

[request setValue:@"\"http://tempuri.org/EmployeesLoginMethod\"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[request setHTTPBody:[requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]] ;

NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData * urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

NSString* responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[urlData bytes]];
   NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
if (urlData)
{
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: response is coming in Xml

Comment: neither Dictionary nor array

Comment: I did that too also Check my question once again there I am getting string like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got you response in json string then try like below,

```
 NSError *jsonError;
 NSData *objectData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                    error:&jsonError];
```

here `responseString` is final output json string that you have posted in question.

Then fetch data from `json dictionary`.

If this scenario will not work then take a look at [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/), you can refer [Appcoda's tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/parse-xml-and-json-web-service/).

Comment: I tried XMLParsing also there I am getting the Value in this Format [{
  "sms": "You have logged in successfully!",
  "userId": "13",
  "type": "1",
  "name": "Suhashini Kumari Singh"
 }]

Comment: How To get the Values of sms.,type,name in the above string

Comment: In XML Parsing We get only String Like [{ "sms": "You have logged in successfully!", "userId": "13", "type": "1", "name": "Suhashini Kumari Singh" }]

Comment: you should convert it in dictionary by xml parsing instead of string or else you need `json string` and then you can convert it to dictionary as i mentioned in my answer!!

Comment: @DineshGurrapu this is not a string, it is a array of dictionary.

Comment: That is array fine but That is coming in a string like this <EmployeesLoginMethodResult>[{"sms":"You have logged in successfully!","userId":"29","type":"1","name":"mng 56 78"}]</EmployeesLoginMethodResult>

Comment: If it is array then you can use my previous answer on your previous question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289301/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-below-output-in-ios/39289529#39289529](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289301/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-below-output-in-ios/39289529#39289529)

Comment: I Used that one also I am not getting the value @KetanParmar

Comment: give me your username,password,ip, and device name (i.e. neccessary parameter) if possible, then i will try. because you not understanding concept properly!!!

Answer (score 4):

Please try XMLDictionary library. For more reference https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

Just convert your NSData to NSDictionary using XMLDictionary as below

```
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLData:returnData];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML to JSON converter (XMLReader)
: https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader

```
#import "XMLReader.h"
```

Here is the sample snippet for your code :

```
NSData * urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (urlData)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:urlData error:&error];
              NSLog(@"-----%@-----",dict);
NSError *jsonError;
        NSString *json2 = [[[[[[dict valueForKey:@"soap:Envelope"] valueForKey:@"soap:Body"] valueForKey:@"EmployeesLoginMethodResponse"] valueForKey:@"EmployeesLoginMethodResult"] valueForKey:@"text"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\""];

        NSData *objectData1 = [json2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

        NSLog(@"-----%@-----",json1);
    }
```

Comment: Yes,but Thats not a problem.

Comment: can you please explain where you exactly facing problem? @DineshGurrapu

Comment: ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><EmployeesLoginMethodResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><EmployeesLoginMethodResult>[{"sms":"You have logged in successfully!","userId":"29","type":"1","name":"mng 56 78"}]</EmployeesLoginMethodResult></EmployeesLoginMethodResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope> `

Comment: This is Coming As NSData

Comment: If I perform XMLParsing I am getting the String like    this                      [{
  "sms": "You have logged in successfully!",
  "userId": "13",
  "type": "1",
  "name": "Suhashini Kumari Singh"
 }] How to get **sms** ,**name**

Comment: If I perform Json Parsing JsonData Coming as null

Comment: so you just want to convert below string to dictionary and want to access **sms**,**name**,..etc?[{ "sms": "You have logged in successfully!", "userId": "13", "type": "1", "name": "Suhashini Kumari Singh" }]

Comment: How to convert string to dictionary @Maddyヅヅ

Comment: You can convert json string to jsonObject(dict or array) as i have mentioned in my answer but you can't convert normal string to jsonObject. example of json string : `@"{\"2\":\"3\"}"`

Comment: Here is the way from which you can get your required result :  NSError *jsonError;
        NSString *json2 = [[[[[[dict valueForKey:@"soap:Envelope"] valueForKey:@"soap:Body"] valueForKey:@"EmployeesLoginMethodResponse"] valueForKey:@"EmployeesLoginMethodResult"] valueForKey:@"text"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\""];
        NSData *objectData1 = [json2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
  NSLog(@"-----%@-----",json1);

Answer (score 0):

It's `nil` because it's not the JSON parsing that's failing but because of the conditional type cast of the resulting object as a dictionary.

It's an array with one item which is dictionary. So, during parsing cast it as a `NSArray`.

Like,

Instead of:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&error];
```

Use:

```
NSArray *arrJson=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&error];

NSDictionary *json = [arrJson objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *sms=[json valueForKey:@"sms"];
NSString *userId=[json valueForKey:@"userId"];
NSString *type=[json valueForKey:@"type"];
NSString *name=[json valueForKey:@"name"];
```